# Change cell background color based on value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this function that takes in a 2d array and creates a table. I want to change the cell background color based on the value in the cell. ex. (if cellVal > 0 change background to green)

```
//function to create the table
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var row = {};
  var cell = {};

  tableData.forEach(function (rowData) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    rowData.forEach(function (cellData) {
      cell = row.insertCell();

      cell.textContent = cellData;
    });
  });
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
createTable(transpose_array)

//css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;

}
```

Comment: insert html and css pls

Comment: td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    
}

Comment: theres no html. All created by the function

Answer (score 0):

```js
let transpose_array = [
  [['a', 3], ['b', -2], ['c', 4]], 
  [[1, -3], [2, 2], [3, -1]]
]

function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  let row;
  let cell;

  tableData.forEach(function (rowData) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    rowData.forEach(function (cellData) {
      cell = row.insertCell();
      
      cell.textContent = cellData[0];
      let cellVal = cellData[1];
      if (cellVal > 0) {
        cell.classList.add('green')
      }
    });
  });
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
createTable(transpose_array)
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
 }
```

Comment: Better use `.classList.add('green')` and create for this CSS instead of inline-CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableData.forEach(function (rowData,i) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.textContent = row_headings[i];

    rowData.forEach(function (cellData) {
      cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.textContent = cellData;
      let cellVal = cellData;
      //make cells different shaeds of green and red for pos/neg (based on %)
      if (cellVal > 0) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#00e100';
      } else if (cellVal < 0) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    });
  });
 document.body.appendChild(table);

}
```